# PARSE Rest API curl command to get data from back4app application

Tags: json, rest, parse-platform, back4app

I am trying to have an output of my installation id for a specific timeframe, but I always have `{"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}` returned by REST API via cURL on my back4app.com app.

I was wondering if there is something with my code, since this example works for me:

```
curl -k -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: shsAUNbSadstestuMAMga" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: mvRKtestQ7H" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'where={

"createdAt":{
"$gte":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2018-11-28T00:00:01.274Z"}
}

}' \
--data-urlencode 'limit=20000000000000000000000' \
https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/_Installation
```

but when i include the device type, it is not working for me:

```
curl -k -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: shsAUNbSadstestuMAMga" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: mvRKtestQ7H" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'where={

"deviceType":{"ios"},

"createdAt":{
"$gte":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2018-11-28T00:00:01.274Z"}
}

}' \
--data-urlencode 'limit=20000000000000000000000' \
https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/_Installation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead:

```
"deviceType":{"ios"},
```

Try it:

```
"deviceType":"ios",
```